# Use the Visual Studio command prompt with WiX in a build event

Tags: wix

I've been trying to sign an [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) file in a post build event with the following code

```
signtool sign /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll /f "E:\Products\Tools\DigitalId\Certificate.pfx" /p 1501ocbc /d "Server" "E:\Products\Setup\Server_Setup\ServerSetup\bin\Release\en-US\ServerSetup.msi"
```

This will sign OK with the Visual Studio command prompt and similar code works for C++ projects. However, when building the setup and signing the code with post build events, I get a code error, 9009. After much debugging I have come to the conclusion that WiX is using the ordinary command prompt. How do I get `cmd.exe` in WiX to open with Visual Studio tools?

Or is there another way to sign my packages?

Comment: Why don't you define the event like like this: `"%programw6432%\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1\bin\signtool.exe" sign /t etc..` ? (adapt the path to your install)

Comment: Thank you @simon that worked perfectly. I dont know why I didn't try that..:)

Comment: I'll post as an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define the event like this:

```
"%programw6432%\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1\bin\signtool.exe" sign /t etc..
```

Note: you need to adapt the path to your install (program files, Windows SDK version, etc.), or you could also define your own environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a built-in way of signing MSI files which seems to work correctly with SignTool: [Insignia](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/insignia.htm).

Comment: Hi I seen that but it says "Insignia is a tool used for inscribing an MSI with the digital signatures that its external CABs are signed with." I don't have external cabs, mine are embedded in the MSI and I only want to sign the MSI itself. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes but reading further down, part of it involves using SignTool.exe, which would imply you can use it to do your own signing?

Answer (score 0):

- Register the certificate and use the `/sha1` hashkey - just to be sure the certificate is good (check browser-internetoptions/content/certificate)
- SignTool path - make it explicit as Simon Mourier suggested or put `signtool.exe` in an accesible path
- Choosing postbuild operation - you should sign the MSI file after you've completed all operations upon the MSI file. Any action upon the MSI (INSERT/UPDATE Property) will undo the signing.